# Compare two dates in the shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, date

I am trying to compare two dates in a shell script but I always get a wrong value. This is the code I am using:

```
currenttime=$(date +%H%M%S);
peak_time=$(date -d "$peak_time" '+%H%M%S');

num1=$(($peak_time-$currenttime))
echo $num1
if [ $num1 < 0 ]
then
  echo "peak time is bigger than current"
else
  echo "peak time is smaller than now"
fi
```

I always get

> peak time is bigger than current

Even if it is smaller.

I tried again with static numbers, like this:

```
    if [ 10 < 0 ]
    then
        echo "peak time is bigger than current"
    else
        echo "peak time is smaller than now"
    fi
```

I always get `peak time is bigger than current`. So the `if` statement always prints the first sentence.

Comment: `<` is the stdin redirection. Use `[[` `]]` instead of `[` `]`, or `-lt` instead of `<`.

Comment: I tried with it but still give me the wrong result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also get an error message when you run your script:

```
/home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh: line 7: 0: No such file or directory
```

This is because you are using `<` in a `[ ]`, and that doesn't do arithmetic comparison, it's [input redirection](https://askubuntu.com/q/883786/85695). So `$num1 < 0` means "run the *command* `$num1` and pass it the contents of *file* `0` as input". What you want is `[ $num1 -lt 0 ]`, `-lt` means "less than".

Of course, your script doesn't make sense unless you are setting `peak_time` somewhere. This line:

```
peak_time=$(date -d "$peak_time" '+%H%M%S');
```

Will always print `000000` since when you run it, `$peak_time` has no value:

```
$ peak_time=$(date -d "$peak_time" '+%H%M%S');
$ echo $peak_time 
000000
```

You need to first set `$peak_time` and *then* convert it to a date. for example:

```
$ peak_time="10:05:31"
$ peak_time=$(date -d "$peak_time" '+%H%M%S');
$ echo $peak_time 
100531
```

So, a working version of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
currenttime=$(date +%H%M%S);
peak_time="10:05:31"
peak_time=$(date -d "+1 hour" '+%H%M%S');

num1=$(($peak_time-$currenttime))
echo $num1
if [ $num1 -lt 0 ]
then
  echo "peak time is bigger than current"
else
  echo "peak time is smaller than now"
fi
```